# Count checked checkbox(array) numbers & saving checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

I have an array of checkbox in a table in PHP file like this :

`echo "<td $Blocked><input type =\"checkbox\" name=\"Blocked[]\" value=\"checkblock\" /></td>";`

I am trying to get the value of number of checked checkboxes and save it to DB.

```
$Blocked = 'unchecked';

if ((isset($_POST['edit_tc']))) {
    if (isset($_POST['Blocked'])) {
        if (is_array($_POST['Blocked'])) {
            foreach($_POST['Blocked'] as $value) {
                error_log($value);
            }
        }
        else {
            $value = $_POST['Blocked'];
            error_log($value);
        }

        $Blocked = 'checked';
    }
}
```

"edit_tc" is the Submit button.

How do I take the number of it when the user checks the checkbox & clicks Submit button to save it to a table column?

Comment: This link may help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382979/get-check-box-value-if-checked

Comment: @William Thanks a lot! 
I have another query as to how to save the status of checked checkboxes after submit is clicked.

Comment: Do you want to save comma separated format like 2,4,10,14 ?

Comment: I did not get your query. I meant would like to keep the checkbox checked even after submit is clicked or better option is to hide the click and display text like "Blocked".

Comment: Sorry my bad brother. Can u tell me how you are saving these values in your db?

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes, I think he is little confused.. He doesn't know what he really wants! He didn't add any query for insert. So, does he asking for an query? Nope, he is now asking for "checkbox checked even after submit is clicked"

Comment: Using MYSQL queries, I am saving the values to a table

Comment: @ShaunakShukla thank you for notifying me. But i thought he wanted to show them checked after saving them into db.

Comment: @BVenky give me a little time. I am writing.

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes, then my answer is not appropriate as requirement??

Comment: @Shaunak, sorry for confusing you. I wanted to know how to get the count of checked checkboxes. I know how to save it to DB using MYSQL query. 
As William said, its right. Now I want to keep the checkboxes checked after the page is submitted.

Comment: @BVenky, it's ok!! Refer William's answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess below code will solve all your problem.

```
<?php
$hello = array();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  extract($_POST);
  print_r($hello); //print all checked elements
}
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="hello[]" value="1" <?php if(in_array(1, $hello)){ echo 'checked'; } ?>>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hello[]" value="2" <?php if(in_array(2, $hello)){ echo 'checked'; } ?>>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hello[]" value="3" <?php if(in_array(3, $hello)){ echo 'checked'; } ?>>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hello[]" value="4" <?php if(in_array(4, $hello)){ echo 'checked'; } ?>>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You have to check the value of each checkbox inside the checkbox array you are getting using `in_array`function of PHP.

If you need to understand whole thing, just let me know.

Will be glad to help you out.

Regards.

Comment: I am not using different values. I am using a single value i.e. `value=\"checkblock\"` inside a table data <td></td>

So it is displayed as a column with checkboxes with single value.

Comment: @BVenky, are you using multiple checkboxes with same values?

Comment: @Shaunak, yes you are right. But I am using it in table column.

Comment: Is checkblock a variable or something? @BVenky

Comment: @BVenky, yes I can see as `<td>checkbox</td>`.. but All checkboxes should have different value with same name OR same values with different names!!

Comment: @William, Yes it is given by user to make it blocked test cases. And I take the count and put it to the DB as $blocked.

Comment: So this must be like `$checkblock` and not `checkblock` , am i right @BVenky ??

Comment: Ya, that's why I am using $Blocked in this:
`echo "<td $Blocked><input type =\"checkbox\" name=\"Blocked[]\" value=\"checkblock\" /></td>";`

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes, Please let me know how to save the status of the checked checkboxes after page is submitted.

Comment: Hello @BVenky, you want to save all values in one column or multiple column? Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method...

```
if ((isset($_POST['edit_tc']))) {
  if (isset($_POST['Blocked'])) 
  {
    $data = $_POST['Blocked'];
   foreach ($data as $checkedValue)
   {
     $qry = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Table_name` WHERE `column_id` = '$checkedValue'");
   }
  }
}
```

This is the method that will use to save each value as different records... You can modify that if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use count() function to get total number of checkbox checked by user.
As only those checkbox values are posted to submitted page which are checked by user and if checkbox is not checked , its value will not be submitted. i.e The unchecked checkbox will not exist on submitted page.

USE:

```
    $totalCheckboxChecked=count($_POST['Blocked']);
```