# Unable to handle unchecked checkbox in loop while save

Tags: php, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes in a foreach loop in my code

```
<form method='POST' action='save.php'>
<?php foreach($problems as $problem): ?>
<input type='text' name="month[]"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="is_increased[]" value="1" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

When I save, I got values of checked checkboxes only. 
How to get all the checkboxes value, it will be '0' if the checkbox is unchecked.
Thank you.

Comment: you may be found your solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382979/get-check-box-value-if-checked

Comment: Thank you. But this topic does not gives any idea about unchecked checkbox. But I need those unchecked values as '0' or false to save.

Comment: your posted code doesn't support the "error" you haven't shown us. Post more and relevant code to the question, including the PHP for it. plus make sure short tags are enabled for `<? endforeach; ?>`

Comment: then this `name=month[]` should be quoted `name="month[]"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- i think he is not asking for the any error!!

Comment: @HardikBhavsar there is no way to give them a solution; not with what they posted for code.

Comment: sorry for my writing mistakes.

Comment: *"When I save, I got values of checked checkboxes only. How to get all the checkboxes value, it will be '0' if the checkbox is unchecked"* - So, where's the code for that? Ok, well, you have answers below; ask them. No sense in me guessing and posting one.

Comment: Check checkbox checked property using jQuery `if ($("#element").is(":checked")) {
  alert("I'm checked");
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do something like this:

```
<form method='POST' action='save.php'>
<?php $i = 0; foreach($problems as $problem): ?>
<input type='text' name=month[<?php echo $i ?>]/>
<input type='hidden' name="is_increased[<?php echo $i ?>]" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="is_increased[<?php echo $i ?>]" value="1" />
<?php ++$i; endforeach; ?>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

if checkbox is checked, its value is sent to server, but if it is not checked, hidden's value is sent to server

Answer (score 0):

Unchecked boxes are not sent in the post. Catch it in your save.php using:

```
if (isset($_POST['checkbox']))
{ it is checked }
else
{ not checked }
```